# Multisite: should /blog go to a 404 page?

Tags: multisite, permalinks

I have a WP multisite installation. All the posts for the default blog are in the subdirectory /blog. All those URLs are fine, all the category and archive links work well. However, visiting the "www.domain.com/blog/" URL leads to a 404. Is this expected behaviour?

I thought it might be something to do with my particular install, but I checked another and it seems to be the same.

I'm running version 3.2.1

Comment: You have posts on the main multisite blog, correct?

Comment: Yes and the permalinks to those posts work. It's just the 'root' level of the blog that 404s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal.

Make a page called "blog" and use a blog page template and it works.

Proof: http://atypicalife.net/blog/